# Button css text disappear after hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I found a nice button that I want to insert in my Wordpress

but after hover the text disappear in the button, here is two button, the #1 text disappear, the #2 it works perfect. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I would like button #1 work like button#2

[Snippet here](https://codepen.io/douklou/pen/MWaBaGZ)

```
#bouton 1

<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

#boutn 2
    <button class="btn"><span>Hover me!</span></button>

</div>
```

---

```
button#place_order.button.alt {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 17px 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
}

button#place_order.button.alt value {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}

button#place_order.button.alt:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 490%;
  width: 140%;
  background: #78c7d2;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

button#place_order.button.alt:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Your code is behind links, which means it can't be searched by people who have the same question as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: I added it  but then it said too much code so I deleted "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a document order issue. In #2 you have a span which goes on top of the animation. Inside #1 you do not have a extra span around the text so this disappears behind the animation.

You can solve this by adding a span around the text in #1 and give it a z-index of '2', then give the animation, a pseudo element in this case, an z-index of '1'.

**Example**

```
<button type="button" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">
    <span>Place order<span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

button::after {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE: CSS Only (not advised)**

If you cannot update the HTML and cannot use JS, there is another 'trick' that you could use:

```
button.alt:after {
  content: attr(value);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

button.alt:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 490%;
  width: 140%;
  background: #78c7d2;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}

button.alt:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

You add another pseudo element (after) and add your content inside the 'content' property. Accessibility wise I would not recommend this or take at least some measure so screen readers have proper access to the button content.

Also remove the text inside the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order"></button>
```

This way the text isn't repeated twice.

Comment: thank you Dave, I think I can't edit the button, only css, is it any way to edit the css instead html ?

Comment: Hi @ibobo, I've updated my answer to correspond to a CSS only solution. ;)

Comment: thank you a lot Dave, I ll almost able go to sleep.  just do you know why place order is repeated twice ? like "place orderplace order" after hover it appears once as needed
https://codepen.io/douklou/pen/GRpBZja

Comment: To prevent the double text, remove the text inside the button. I've updated the answer, I just forgot to mention it. ;) 
The solution beneath me uses 'mixed-blend-mode', but be careful if you need to support 'older' browsers. Also, the effect changes depending on the colours used, because it is a blend mode, it blends colours. 

**For example** if you would change the background to '#008ca0', the text colour changes on hover from white to blueish. It can have some unexpected results when changing the button colours, use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS3 only solution, you could also add `mix-blend-mode: hard-light;` to `button#place_order.button.alt:after` of the button:

```css
button#place_order.button.alt {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 17px 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.20);
}

button#place_order.button.alt value {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}

button#place_order.button.alt:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 490%;
  width: 140%;
  background: #78c7d2;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-98%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

button#place_order.button.alt:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-9%) translateY(-25%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>
```

Comment: @ibobo glad I could help.